# Meteor: Remote MongoDB with dynamic IP

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

In a local network (over which I supposedly have no control) I need to connect my local instance of a meteor app to a MongoDB that is running on another PC. Using something like `MONGO_URL="mongodb://192.168.1.xx:27017" meteor` I am able to connect to it; However is there some way to connect when **I don't know** the IP, given that it may change daily?

What I'm attempting here would be something like:

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
//Script to find the correct IP
//Connect my app to that MongoDB instance
});
```

In short: is there some way to set the MONGO_URL dynamically?

Thank you

Comment: You can use https://mLab.com

Comment: @Mikhail I forgot to mention that the App is meant to run on a local network only. It's a desktop app based on Meteor.

Answer (score 1):

Use the hostname of the MongoDB server. As long as you have a local DNS server and both computers are using the same DNS server (which is most likely the case unless you have customised the network settings on either PC), the name will be resolved to the IP address.

To get the hostname of the server, type `hostname` into Command Prompt (or Terminal if on a Mac).

Alternatively, even without control over the network you may be able to configure a static IP address on the MongoDB server as long as you have local administrator permissions. Just make sure it is within the same network range as the rest of the network, but try to steer clear of your DHCP range otherwise you may get IP conflicts.

Comment: Thank you. However when I try MONGO_URL="mongodb://SERVER--V1:27017" meteor. I get a "Failed to connect". "SERVER-V1" is the hostname of the PC, 27017 is the open port.

Comment: You might need a fully qualified name, e.g. `server--v1.somedomain.local`. This could be specified by your router when it assigns DHCP or it might be specified by your computer.

Comment: One thing you can try is a reverse DNS lookup - try typing into Command Prompt: `ping -a 192.168.1.xx` and it will query the DNS server for a PTR record and if it exists will give you a host name. There are a number of reasons that this may not work, but it's worth a try

Comment: I understand how difficult it is to troubleshoot network issues remotely. I'll have a long hard look at my network for the time being. However, I still don't  know how I could set the MONGO_URL dynamically, once the app has started. Is that even possible?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Meteor specifically, but your server is unlikely to change IP address while remaining connected to the network except if a router is restarted or something. If it did, it is likely that MongoDB would need to be restarted so that it can listen on the new IP address. As for the client app, every time it establishes a connection it will first query its local DNS cache and use a cached address if it exists, otherwise it will re-query the DNS server. How long your computer caches the address will depend on your DNS server.